# Wordpress - Trouble generating automatic byline in posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have a byline (for example: By [author name]) automatically appear at the top of each post. I'm trying to make this happen through the functions.php file. Right now only the "By" text is displaying, but the aspects that I want to pull in automatically (author name and author url) are not displaying at all.

Also, while I'm getting some of this to show up on the posts page, none of what I'm trying to do is displaying in the homepage post excerpt.

I found some code online and tried to bend it to meet my needs. Here is the code I placed in functions.php:

```
/*
 * add byline to post
 */
    
// Get author's display name
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );

// Get author's website URL
$user_website = get_the_author_meta('url', $post->post_author);

// Author byline and bio link
$author_details = 'By <a href="'. $user_website .'">' . $display_name . '</a>'; 


if ( ! function_exists( 'wpfactory_before_post_content' ) ) {

    function wpfactory_before_post_content( $content ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            $content = 'By <a href="'. $user_website .'">' . $display_name . '</a>' . $content;
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpfactory_before_post_content' );
```

I'm expecting that at the top of post content for every post, a line of text would display that looks like "By [author name]" with just the author's name clickable to the website associated with their user profile.

What is happening is that just the "By" text is displaying:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G4tA.png)

Comment: First of all, you need to determine the author details _inside_ your callback function. Second, you will have to get access to the post object - it does not get passed in as parameter for this hook, but with `global $post;` at the start of your callback function, it should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe is absolutely right with their comment. You need to put all your variables inside the callback function and also get the `$post` variable. It's also a good idea to put the byline inside its own paragraph since posts are also using paragraphs by default.

This is verified to be working when put inside the functions.php:

```
/*
* add byline to post
*/
    
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpfactory_before_post_content' ) ) {

    function wpfactory_before_post_content( $content ) {

        if ( is_single() ) {
            global $post;
            
            // Get author's display name
            $display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );

            // Get author's website URL
            $user_website = get_the_author_meta('url', $post->post_author);

            // Author byline and bio link
            $author_details = '<p>By <a href="'. $user_website .'">' . $display_name . '</a></p>'; 
            return $author_details . $content;
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpfactory_before_post_content' );
```

You might also want to check for the `post_type` to be `post`, because `is_single()` works for any post type, except attachments and pages, so that function might break things for custom post types.

The check for `is_single()` also prevents the byline being used for the excerpt, which is usually desirable, because WordPress will strip all tags from the excerpt, so the link set won't be working.

To also add the byline to the excerpt, I suggest to set it explicitly using this filter function:

```
/*
* add byline to excerpt
*/
    
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpfactory_before_excerpt_content' ) ) {
    function wpfactory_before_excerpt_content( $excerpt ) {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) { // For posts only
            // Get author's display name
            $display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );

            // Get author's website URL
            $user_website = get_the_author_meta('url', $post->post_author);

            // Author byline and bio link
            $author_details = '<p>By <a href="'. $user_website .'">' . $display_name . '</a></p>'; 
            return $author_details . $excerpt;
        }
        return $excerpt;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpfactory_before_excerpt_content' );
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked in the post, but it wasn't showing up on the excerpt on the homepage. I'm thinking something needs to happen on the content.php. I tried this code in content.php but it just shows "By" with no hyperlinked author name. 

<p>
By <a href="<?php $author_details ?>"></a>
</p>

Comment: If you're using `the_excerpt()` or `get_the_excerpt()` you can use their filter hook `get_the_excerpt` or `the_excerpt`. Do you want me to update my answer?

Comment: Updating the answer would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @LukeKelly Done!

Comment: @LukeKelly Is it working as expected? If so, please accept the answer (and upvote if you can).